# Can we buy new clothes for baby during the 8th month of pregnancy?

Tags: halal-haram, pregnancy

Can we buy new clothes things for unborn baby ,during 8th month of pregnancy ? 
Many people tell it is not good to do like that is it true according to Islam ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Islam, do whatever you want for your coming baby. Islam asks us to be optimistic about future.

May good protect you and your baby.

Comment: Some evidences supporting your claims would make this answer more helpful. (see [answer]).